# http-basic auth, else placeholder-page

Tags: htaccess, apache, authentication

Is it possible to show a http-basic-auth, and when someone fails that test, show a certain HTML-placeholder-page?
If so, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726860/apache-authentication-redirect-on-failure-reliably

Basically you send a html file as error document that does a redirect to your placeholder page:

```
<Location "/protected">
    AuthUserFile /path/to/users
    AuthName "This is protected area"
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user

    #ErrorDocument 401 /register.html
    ErrorDocument 401 "<html><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=/register.html\"></html>"
</Location>
```